# SQLITE getting trigger to check against table1 and insert into table2

Tags: sqlite

I have a reservation table which the user will insert records into.
The User does not select the car just the type.

Once the record is inserted I want some triggers to do the following:-

The date and vehicle combination to a log file the data and vehicle are UNIQUE(date,car) so the same reservation cannot be made twice therefore a car cannot be double booked.

SO my issue is how do I now get the trigger to select the next available car of that type?

I can get it to select the next car by just saying Car.carid != Log.carid  but that is not using the date as a second check so I could not then use the vehicle on another date.

Simply putting AND between the check doesnt work meaning 
WHERE Car.carid != Log.carid AND Reservation.date != C.datewhen

Some guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Before you think in triggers, you must realize what SQL statements must be used to perform operation manually!

Comment: hey LS_dev thanks yes I am trying to do that but I was only able to get based on car OR based on type not both. But yes method wise I fully agree and as a noob am trying!

Answer (score 0):

I think this query is what you are after...

```
SELECT      MIN(c.carid)
FROM        all_cars c
WHERE       c.type = 'CAR TYPE'
    AND NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT     1
         FROM       reservation r
         WHERE      r.date = 'THE DATE'
            AND r.carid = c.carid)
```

If the query returns a NULL value then no cars are available.
Or you could take off the MIN and just use the first record returned.

Comment: Hey Adrian,  I just ran this and I can see where you're going with it.  Using MIN it returns the lowest number as if I had an ORDER BY.  I need to add this to my query and see if it works as I need it to.  That said I think that I might need to look at exactly what it is I need to have as a result.  Thanks